# Best Superpowers Gained From Arthopod Essence?

Tags: science-fiction, culture, low-fantasy

Please assume the following:

1. Humans were taken by aliens and relocated to another planet. They have no memory of this event.
2. High oxygen levels and alien alterations (which made them capable of surviving at large sizes) allow giant arthropods to exist.
3. Due to powerful psionics and advanced knowledge, the aliens have abilities that appear to be magical (ie. can alter reality). They put some of this magic into humans along with the idea that defeating a creature causes one to gain power from it. This idea is obviously false, but thanks to the magic, a placebo effect became real.

In other words, they can take abilities from arthropods by killing them! So, my question is:

What abilities will be the most useful to these people? Crustaceans, insects, and arachnids are all fair game.

Comment: Uh...anything you want? This is a writing prompt, not something I think anybody can actually answer conclusively. It could lead anywhere from extreme pacifism to all consuming violence and warfare. Most likely multiple groups would form that hold onto ideas group somewhere in this spectrum. The more violent ones might even turn to killing other humans. Hey, taking the powers of your foes works, right? Humans have also done this here, on Earth without anything to really back it up. So you can write for the fall of humanity, if you wish.

Comment: Good point, I should really change this question.....

Comment: This is a...radical change to the question. Now I have to ask - what does it mean to "gain abilities" from slaying insects? Is this comic book rules, where killing spiders will somehow allow you to cling to walls? Do people even have a choice for what ability they get? E.g., if they kill a spider, they may choose wall climbing or spider senses. Or is it random(-ish)?

Comment: forget arthropods go for echinoderms, ultimate regeneration and immortality.

Comment: Great idea, I will consider that.

Comment: For close voters, another question like this was well received once: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/103703/21222

Comment: Oh yes! I loved that question, so I came up with my own version =)....

Comment: Further reading: Shadows of the Apt, by Adrian Tchaikovsky

Answer (score 2):

### A few Ideas:

**Mind control:** Kill the giant arthropod hive queen, control the underlings. Alternately pith enemies like the emerald cockroach wasp and take control of their bodies (useful in a world with lots of giant insects).

**Reproduction:** Kill enemies, inject an "egg" and a new version of you hatches from the corpse. (this seems to fit well with the theme). Hatch tiny servant insects that do your bidding. Become a colony organism and divide your body into hundreds of sub-parts that can act independently.

**Body modification:** Multiple limbs, slashing/stabbing appendages, wings to fly, super-jump. Compound eyes allowing 360 degree vision, abilities to see outside human spectrums. Poison stinger.

**Size handwavium:** Become tiny. Walk on water/climb walls (normally only due to small size). Super strength/carapace (I agree with Square-Cube Law on this one, +1)

Comment: Okay, so going off your answer, I would assume a more Xenomorph-type method for reproduction-implant an egg made of a bit of your essence, it'll absorb and combine with the victim's to create a new organism. As for becoming a colony organism, wouldn't it be better to become a hive or swarm? Or is that what you meant?

Comment: @Alendyias You could go a number of ways, depending on how you wanted it. An implanted egg could be like cloning/replicants (if you wanted, even w. memories, etc.) or it could be creating human-insect hybrids loyal to the creator (an awesome supervillain ability). I meant a kind of hive organism (I think the Mummy in the movie could turn into a mass of beetles) that could spy remotely, climb under doors, or leave a part behind and recreate the individual if killed.

Answer (score 1):

The one thing in common about all arthropods is the hard shell and the incredible strength (the latter might be lost on giant ones due to Square Cubes).

Also one of the most common self assessment illusions for humans is the feeling that they are much tougher than they actually are. This is widespread specially in young males, and is kinda the income source for darwinawards dot com.

So most people might believe that by killing a giant lobster/crab/spider/ant they will become more resistant to damage, and the Clarkean magic will ensure it happens. They could then put their newfound abilities to test in a Marvelesque version of Jackass. I would pay to watch that.

Comment: According to the information above, they actually do; if someone took out an Indomitable Ironclad Beetle, they could gain equivalent durability. This beetle can survive being RUN OVER on a gravel road, so....would you pay to watch someone like that being smacked around?

Comment: @Alendyias my bad, I've fixed the answer. And yes, I already paid a lot of money to watch things like that whenever Disney released a new MCU movie... A real world experience like that would be much cooler.

Comment: Thank you! Interesting to note that people would pay to watch things like that....it might lead to an emphasis on gladiatorial combat in this world.....

Comment: @Alendyias that is basically what Marvel's [Mojoworld](https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Mojoworld) is all about: non-stop televised super-gladiatorial combat, because the inhabitants love to see some super beings taking a kick to the noggin'. Longshot is a survivor and one of my favorite Marvel characters.